# Chrome 32 html5 video loading delay, no sound

Tags: html, google-chrome, video

Chrome Version: 32.0.1700.76 m
Operating System: Windows 7

I've been having issues with Chrome's html5 video player. Two concerns:

1. The video won't begin to play until the entire video buffers. The loading bar shows the video loading slowly until the entire video is loaded and then it begins to play the video. This takes a while for people with slow internet and they may think the video is broken if it doesn't begin playing within 10-15 seconds.
2. When the video plays there is no sound. The image shows but there isn't any sound. The only sound is a random .5 second sound clip while the video is buffering.

I would very much appreciate some help troubleshooting these problems or possible alternate solution ideas.

Page with video problems:
http://suntmormon.ro/actiuni-umanitare/

Here's one video that doesn't play at all in Chrome. It may be an unrelated problem:
http://suntmormon.ro/wp-content/uploads/2014/01/Mormon-Missionaries.mp4

-Davis

Comment: Maybe this has something to do with it: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13705409/mp4-in-video-js-not-playing-until-fully-loaded

Comment: I did find a decent workaround solution - I converted the videos to webm format and added that source alongside the mp4 format. The problem only occurs with the mp4 videos. It also depends on which source is listed first.

Look at this example http://jsfiddle.net/5k7DF/2/
If I put the webm source first it works. If I put the mp4 source first it has those problems.