# Why my mp4 is not played until fully loaded inside the video tag?

Tags: html, html5-video, mp4

I have a video file like [this](https://v2.globalassessment.com.tr/api/videos/dOaEwXALOzUd-1-ALL.mp4) which I am not able to play in the browser unless it is fully loaded. I am using the code below to play my files and I have been successful with all mp4s remotely being loaded except the ones I recorded as such. How can I play these files on my browser without having to wait for them to be fully loaded?

```
<html>
<body>

<h1>The video src attribute</h1>

<video width="320" height="240" controls src="movie.ogg">
  Your browser does not support the video tag.
</video>

<p><b>Note:</b> The .ogg fileformat is not supported in old IE and Safari.</p>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: This issue is most likely due to the file itself, so there is nothing you could do client-side to solve this. Check out this thread https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13705409/mp4-in-video-js-not-playing-until-fully-loaded